# Accessing query result fields

Tags: apex, soql, query

I am trying to pull values from a query result I'm performing on the `Product2` sObject and am trying to save the values from the query into individual variables.

My query result:

```
|DEBUG|product_query: (Product2:{ProductCode=88-7799, Id=01t1U000009Uf2IPGS})
```

I have tried using `internal_product_code = product_query.get('ProductCode')` but am unable to pull any of the values out. I keep getting the following error `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(String) from the type List<Product2>`. Is there another way to access this value?

```
product_query = [Select ProductCode 
                                     From Product2
                                     Where Name = :current_sensor];

                    System.debug('product_query: ' + product_query);

                    String internal_product_code = product_query.get('ProductCode');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest going through the Apex developer guide once.

As to answer your question, it depends on the variable type. I think yours is the second case.

> Case 1

If your query looks like this :

```
Product2 product_query = [Select ProductCode From Product2 Where Name = :current_sensor];
```

then the result accessed via (You will get QueryException if more than one record is returned)

```
String internal_product_code = product_query.ProductCode;
```

or via casting the result to SObject and then using get methods of SObject class.

```
String internal_product_code = ((SObject) product_query).get('ProductCode');
```

---

> Case 2

If your query looks like this

```
List<Product2> product_query = [Select ProductCode From Product2 Where Name = :current_sensor];
```

then you will have to iterate over the list

```
for(Product2 productRecord: products_query){
// Do something here
String value = productRecord.ProductCode
}
```

or you can access the value directly based on the index.

```
if(!product_query.isEmpty()){
String productCode = product_query.get(0).ProductCode
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help